# How to properly reduce scale and format a Float value in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to properly reduce scale, formatting a float value and returning it as a String in Swift.

For example:

```
let value: Float = 4.8962965

// formattedFalue should be 4.90 or 4,90 based on localization
let formattedValue = value.formatNumber()
```

Here is what I did:

```
extension Float {

func reduceScale(to places: Int) -> Float {
      let multiplier = pow(10, Float(places))
      let newDecimal = multiplier * self // move the decimal right
      let truncated = Float(Int(newDecimal)) // drop the fraction
      let originalDecimal = truncated / multiplier // move the decimal back                 return originalDecimal
 }

func formatNumber() -> String {
      let num = abs(self)

      let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
      numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
      numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
      numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
      numberFormatter.roundingMode = .up
      numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
      numberFormatter.locale = // we take it from app settings 

      let formatted = num.reduceScale(to: 2)
      let returningString = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: formatted))!
      return "\(returningString)"

}

}
```

But when I use this code I get 4.89 (or 4,89 depending on the localization) instead of 4.90 (or 4,90) as I expect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove that `reduceScale` method which is not necessary and it will probably work as expected. You are truncating the decimal to `4.89` which cannot be rounded any more (it is already rounded).

Comment: Hi @Sulthan thanks for your reply. I removed the reduceScale method and now I'm returning directly let returningString = currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: num))! but I get 4.9.

Comment: That's because you have specified `minimumFractionDigits = 0`. If you always want to display two decimal digits, you will have to set `minimumFractionDigits = 2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sulthan now it is working as expected! I don't always want minimumFractionDigits to be 0, so I'll pass it dynamically as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You get 4.89 because `reduceScale(to:)` turns the number into `4.89` (actually, probably `4.89000something` because 4.89 cannot be expressed exactly as a binary floating point). When the number formatter truncates this to two decimal places, it naturally rounds it down.

In fact, you don't need `reduceScale(to:)` at all because the rounding function of the number formatter will do it for you.

Also the final string interpolation is unnecessary because the result of `NumberFormatter.string(from:)` is automatically bridged to a `String?`

Also (see comments below by Dávid Pásztor and Sulthan) you can use `string(for:)` to obviate the `NSNumber` conversion.

This is what you need

```
import Foundation

extension Float {

    func formatNumber() -> String {
          let num = abs(self)

          let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
          numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
          numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
          numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
          numberFormatter.roundingMode = .up
          numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
          numberFormatter.locale = whatever
          return numberFormatter.string(for: num)!
    }
}

let value: Float = 4.8962965

// formattedFalue should be 4.90 or 4,90 based on localization
let formattedValue = value.formatNumber() // "4.9"
```

Comment: you can also use `string(from:)` to avoid using `NSNumber`.

Comment: @Sulthan I tried that in a playground and it errored saying it needed an `NSNumber`

Comment: @JeremyP `string(for:)` is the alternative that takes any numeric types rather than just `NSNumber`

Comment: all right, I mixed the two :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by following [Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan)'s comments:

> remove that `reduceScale` method which is not necessary and it will probably work as expected. You are truncating the decimal to `4.89` which cannot be rounded any more (it is already rounded). – [Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan) [6 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74287403/how-to-properly-reduce-scale-and-format-a-float-value-in-swift/74287759#comment131152331_74287403)

> That's because you have specified `minimumFractionDigits = 0`. If you always want to display two decimal digits, you will have to set `minimumFractionDigits = 2`. – [Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan) [5 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74287403/how-to-properly-reduce-scale-and-format-a-float-value-in-swift/74287759#comment131152825_74287403)

Answer (score 0):

`Foundation` has a better API now.

In-place, you can use `.number`:

```swift
value.formatted(.number
  .precision(.fractionLength(2))
  .locale(locale)
)
```

But it's only available on specific types. For an extension for more than one floating-point type, you'll need to use the equivalent initializer instead:

```swift
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
  var formattedTo2Places: String {
    formatted(FloatingPointFormatStyle()
      .precision(.fractionLength(2))
      .locale(locale)
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
let locale = Locale(identifier: "it")
(4.8962965 as Float).formattedTo2Places // 4,90
```